# not able to connect to the sql server using sql + node.js + virtual studio code

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to connect MySQL server using SQl and Node.js with Virtual studio code but couldn't. My code is as followed:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "test",
    multipleStatements : true
});

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=> {
    if(!err)
    {
        console.log("Connected");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Connection Failed");
    }

})
app.listen(3000);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! actually it is a problem of MySQL 8.0, which uses caching_sha2_password as default authentication plugin.

Run the following code in MySQL line cmd

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your new password'; 
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your new password';
```

And it worked!